# Import existing Symfony project in PHPEdit

Tags: php, editor, symfony-1.4

I've recently downloaded an evaluation copy of PHPEdit because I saw it supports Symfony. I've managed to build a new project, but the problem is that I already have an existing project which is almost completed.
Is there any possibility to easily import these files in PHPEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't import existing Symfony project in PHPEdit directly. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

currently there is no option to create new project from existing source code
what you can do is create new project in phpedit and then 
go in the project folder there you will find file call project file with the name you given to your new project having extension called .PHPEditProject copy it and paste to your existing symfony project directory and then open that file with text editor and then update file with your project name that it and now your can open that file with phpedit or simply double click that's it 
hope this will help u.

```
<set:Property key="Languages">
  <set:Property key="PHP">
    <set:Property key="RootNamespace">
      <set:Data>Your project name </set:Data>
    </set:Property>
  </set:Property>
</set:Property>
```